# AngularJS with Angular-UI datepicker & timepicker - formatted model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using ng-repeat to cycle through my returned fields. Every field can have few types, e.g. TextField, NumericField, also DateTimeField.

So I'm looking which type it is and showing that needed input:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <div ng-show="field.fieldtype == 'TextField'">
        <input type="text" ng-model="DATA.values[field.key]" />
    </div>

    <div ng-show="field.fieldtype == 'NumericField'">
        <input type="number" ng-model="DATA.values[field.key]" />
    </div>

    <div ng-show="field.fieldtype == 'DateTimeField'">
        <datepicker ng-model="DATA.values[field.key]"></datepicker>
        <timepicker ng-model="DATA.values[field.key]"></timepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything was working as expected until I added datepicker and timepicker. Now my model gets formatted all the time even field type is not DateTimeField, and when entering a value (e.g. in a TextField), I'm getting errors:

```
Timepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.
```

Can I tell somehow to those pickers to not format my model or is there any other solution?

Comment: What does `DATA.values[field.key]` contain exactly?

Comment: It stores entered value. If field is described as TextField, so it's a string, if it's NumericField - it should be a number. But I'm not formatting this model anyhow myself - I just do I simple validation afterwords. And seems like date/time pickers formats that field into Date/Time format.

Comment: if you dont want valid date/time, then use input[text]

Comment: Can I make it inline (embedded) when using input[text]?

Comment: could you provide an example of entered value?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a Date object as model. In the controller, try something like the following:

```
$scope.DATA = { values: {} };
angular.forEach(fields, function (field) {
    switch (field.fieldtype) {
        case 'DateTimeField';
        case 'NumericField';
            var date = new Date();
            $scope.DATA.values[field.key] = date.toISOString();
            break;
        case 'TextField'
            $scope.DATA.values[field.key] = '';
            break;
    }
});
```

This sets the date to 'now' for each datepicker and timepicker, and to an empty string for a text field.

When you need to send it to a server or something, you have to change it to a string or number when sending the request.

Comment: But I want to do the opposite - I don't want my field to be formatted as a date.

Comment: What format do you want then? It is a date picker.. so the input and output is date.. When you need to send it to a server or something, you have to change it to a string or number when sending the request.

Comment: Simple text... So that my model doesn't puts many errors if a string is entered in it.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is a string now, following the ISO 8601 date/time format. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601